# Gracefully shutdown UNIX-socket server on NodeJS running under Forever

Tags: node.js, unix-socket, forever

I have an NodeJS application which sets up a UNIX-socket to expose some interprocess communication channel (some kind of monitoring stuff). UNIX-socket file is placed in `os.tmpdir()` folder (i.e. `/tmp/app-monitor.sock`).

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(...);
server.listen('/tmp/app-monitor.sock', ...);
```

I use a signal handling (SIGINT, SITERM, etc...) to gracefully shutdown my server and remove a socket file.

```
function shutdown() {
    server.close(); // socket file is automatically removed here
    process.exit();
}

process.on('SIGINT', shutdown);
// and so on
```

My application is running with `forever start ...` to monitor it's lifecycle.

I have a problem with `forever restartall` command. When forever doing `restartall` it's using a `SIGKILL` to terminate all child processes. `SIGKILL` can't be handled by a process so my app dies without any shutdown procedures.

The problem is a socket file which is not removed when `SIGKILL` is used. After the child process is restarted, new server can't be started cause' a `listen` call will cause a `EADDRINUSE` error.

I can't remove a existing socket file during an app startup cause' I don't know if it a real working socket or some traces of a previous unclean shutdown.

So, the question is... What is the better way to handle such situation (SIGKILL and UNIX-socket server)?

Comment: did u read this http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_signal_events

Comment: Yes, and did u read my question?

Comment: no I did not read. It is easy to say than do. If you do not mind to modify the code in forever, then forever/node_modules/forever-monitor/lib/forever-monitor/monitor.js, in fuunction Monitor.prototype.kill add the SIGINT before forever send the SIGKILL signal

Comment: @wayne This is a bad solution. I don't want to modify 3rd party software. Also, my process may be killed with SIGKILL without forever...

Comment: FYI [node-dev](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev) sends a `SIGTERM` which is catchable.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As other people have mentioned, you cannot do anything in response to SIGKILL, which is in general why `forever` (and everybody else) should not be using SIGKILL except in extreme circumstances.  So the best you can do is clean up in another process.

I suggest you clean up on start.  When you get `EADDRINUSE`, try to connect to the socket.  If the socket connection succeeds, another server is running and so this instance should exit.  If the connection fails then it is safe to unlink the socket file and create a new one.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
    console.log('server connected');
    c.on('end', function() {
        console.log('server disconnected');
    });
    c.write('hello\r\n');
    c.pipe(c);
});

server.on('error', function (e) {
    if (e.code == 'EADDRINUSE') {
        var clientSocket = new net.Socket();
        clientSocket.on('error', function(e) { // handle error trying to talk to server
            if (e.code == 'ECONNREFUSED') {  // No other server listening
                fs.unlinkSync('/tmp/app-monitor.sock');
                server.listen('/tmp/app-monitor.sock', function() { //'listening' listener
                    console.log('server recovered');
                });
            }
        });
        clientSocket.connect({path: '/tmp/app-monitor.sock'}, function() { 
            console.log('Server running, giving up...');
            process.exit();
        });
    }
});

server.listen('/tmp/app-monitor.sock', function() { //'listening' listener
    console.log('server bound');
});
```

Comment: Great answer. Just one "error": when you call `fs.unlink` you should pass a callback, and restart the `server.listen` again on that callback. This way you never try to connect before unlinking (also node warns `fs: missing callback` when not using a callback).

Comment: @TheBronx please edit the answer to include your recommendation/improvement.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: It blows my mind how the whitespace edit from 2 spaces to 4 spaces was approved for this.

Comment: @Claudius: So true, I actually tried to reject it but was too late.

Comment: It's a good thing Old Pro invited the edit. That makes up for a lot.

Comment: That's how I got here, I was a few seconds late

Comment: Yup, it wasn't just whitespace :)

Comment: @TheBronx, Because this is a server startup issue with a practically unavoidable race condition, I want to use a synchronous unlink function to minimize the time between deleting the socket and creating a new one. I believe `fs.unlink` was synchronous when I wrote this (I certainly didn't get a warning when I ran it) but now that there is an explicitly synchronous version I replaced your change with that.

Comment: I wrote a simple npm package that implements this for easy usage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/server-starter

Comment: Here's a gist that gracefully starts the server for you, and deletes stale socket files: https://gist.github.com/ericvicenti/876e2df1103232f1fe6781c927e0eb63

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to use SIGTERM to do what you want: 
`process.on('SIGTERM', shutdown)`

Comment: I am able to handle `SIGTERM`, but `forever` restarts child processes by `SIGKILL`

Comment: @Olegas - `forever` has an option to change the SIG used when it stops a process.  You can change it to SIGTERM.

Answer (score 1):

```
server.on('error', function (e) {
  if (e.code == 'EADDRINUSE') {
    console.log('Address in use, retrying...');
    setTimeout(function () {
      server.close();
      server.listen(PORT, HOST);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback

**UPD**

you cant handle SIGKILL, then you must cleanup socket manual

this example work fine with forever

```
var fs = require('fs');
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) {});
server.listen('./app-monitor.sock', function() {
  console.log('server bound');
});

server.on('error', function (e) {
  if (e.code == 'EADDRINUSE') {
    console.log('Address in use, retrying...');
    setTimeout(function () {
      fs.unlink('./app-monitor.sock');
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: But `EADDRINUSE` in case of file-socket server means that socket file exists. It won't ever close or disappear, cause' parent app is already dead, killed with `SIGKILL`

Comment: SIGKILL close programm immediately use fs.unlink instead server.close()

Comment: ... and I'll potentially kill a socket from another running instance.

Comment: UNIX sockets are file system entities, you need to clean them up after you're done. Make sure you call server.close() before you exit. if you can't do that, than you must fix it in forever-monitor to send another signal or in your application via fs.unlink

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot handle `SIGKILL` and you want to use forever (which uses `SIGKILL`) you will have to use a workaround.

For example, first send a signal to shutdown your server and then do the forever restart:

```
kill -s SIGUSR1 $pid
# $pid contains the pid of your node process, or use
# killall -SIGUSR1 node

sleep 2
forever restart test.js
```

In your js handle SIGUSR1:

```
process.on('SIGUSR1', gracefullyShutdownMyServer);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must choose

1. change SIGKILL to another signal in forever-monitor to handle in app
2. take care of your app in this case, using fs.unlink
3. stop using forever